# Way to make a task issue success only when all the children tasks have finished successfully?

Tags: celery, celery-task

all,

I have a question regarding Celery. Let’s suppose I have the following Celery tasks:

```
@celery_app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


@celery_app.task
def task_no(n):
    return f'Finished task {n}.'


@celery_app.task
def add_bunch():
    return chord([add.si(1, 1), add.si(2, 2)])(task_no.si('1'))


@celery_app.task
def do_it_all():
    chain(
        add_bunch.si(),
        task_no.si('2')
    ).apply_async()
```

If I run do_it_all() , I get the following output:

```
[INFO/MainProcess] Received task: lumi_translation.celery_tasks.add_bunch[d40dc179-602d-4414-9fbd-ee8d62fe7604]  
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task lumi_translation.celery_tasks.add_bunch[d40dc179-602d-4414-9fbd-ee8d62fe7604] succeeded in 0.01651039347052574s: <AsyncResult: d5564664-1e6f-445f-a172-442fef547422>
[INFO/MainProcess] Received task: lumi_translation.celery_tasks.add[fbc7288a-1f76-447a-ac2b-906ddaa6c00c]  
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task lumi_translation.celery_tasks.add[fbc7288a-1f76-447a-ac2b-906ddaa6c00c] succeeded in 0.0005592871457338333s: 2
[INFO/MainProcess] Received task: lumi_translation.celery_tasks.add[472d6142-355d-466b-8ee4-0d8cc7e1d96e]  
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task lumi_translation.celery_tasks.add[472d6142-355d-466b-8ee4-0d8cc7e1d96e] succeeded in 0.0012424923479557037s: 4
[INFO/MainProcess] Received task: lumi_translation.celery_tasks.task_no[faa013e7-42c5-4321-b132-e749169810ee]  
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task lumi_translation.celery_tasks.task_no[faa013e7-42c5-4321-b132-e749169810ee] succeeded in 0.0003700973466038704s: 'Finished task 2.'
[INFO/MainProcess] Received task: lumi_translation.celery_tasks.task_no[d5564664-1e6f-445f-a172-442fef547422]  
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task lumi_translation.celery_tasks.task_no[d5564664-1e6f-445f-a172-442fef547422] succeeded in 0.0003337441012263298s: 'Finished task 1.'
```

`add_bunch` task issues success even when the children tasks have not finished; hence, task 2 finishes before task 1. Is there a way to make the `add_bunch`  task issue success only when all the children tasks have finished successfully? In the above example, is there a way to make sure task 1 finishes before task 2?

Answer (score 0):

add_bunch() does "nothing", it just creates a Chord object and returns it. This is always going to succeed, ie. to return a valid Chord object unless, of course, if it can't allocate any more memory...

Comment: Hi DejanLekic,
Thanks for the reply. I think add_bunch() not only creates a Chord object but also executes it. So, I was wondering if there is a way to make the add_bunch task issue success only when all the children tasks (add() and task_no()) have finished successfully?

Comment: You are absolutely right - it does execute, but the return statement just returns the whatever underlying result object is there... It will always succeed. I will update/improve the answer if I find some time...

Comment: Thanks. I am hoping to find a way to make add_bunch() task delay issuing 'success' until all children tasks have succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

One of my coworkers showed me a workaround to do this. He said that he had spent a really unreasonable amount of time figuring it out. I am putting it out here so it will save someone else the trouble.

A workable rewrite of the `add_bunch()` task is:

```
@celery_app.task(bind=True)
def add_bunch(self):
    self.replace(
        chord(header=[add.si(1, 1), add.si(2, 2)], body=task_no.si('1'))
    )
```